# React-scroll change state of Link element

Tags: reactjs, react-router

So basically on a homepage of app I have a sections with career details blocks.
When clicking on one of them react-router redirects onto new view, something like - `/careers/position1`.

So I want to keep Career link active only not other ones (https://gyazo.com/f9da42d9a1d427c66e54026421fa2b6b).

Code:

```
class Career extends React.Component {
render() {
    let vacancies;
    if (!this.props.vacancies.length) {
        vacancies = <p>Sorry, no vacations currently available.</p>
    } else {
        vacancies = this.props.vacancies.map((item) => (
            <Link
      to={`/careers/${item.Id}`}
                className='career_position'
                key={item.Id}>
                {item.Title}
                {!!+item.IsHot && <LazyImg src={FireLogo} alt='Hot vacancy' />}
            </Link>
        ))
    }
    return (
        <div className='career_container'>
            <h1 className='section_heading'>Career</h1>
            <div className="section_content">
                <h3>We are hiring! Please, do not hestitate to contact us regarding any questions you might have.</h3>
                <div className='career_content_wrapper'>
                    <div className='career_recruiter'>
                        <LazyImg src={CareerRec} alt="Recruiter" />
                        <h2>Mary</h2>
                        <h3>recruiter@leobit.co</h3>
                        <a href="#" className="social_profile"><LazyImg src={LinkEdin} alt="Linkedin profile" /></a>
                        <a href="#" className="social_profile"><LazyImg src={Skype} alt="Skype profile" /></a>
                    </div>
                    <div className='career_positions_container'>
                        {vacancies}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
}
```

Comment: Could you please include your code in the question?

Comment: https://gyazo.com/f9da42d9a1d427c66e54026421fa2b6b

The screen below is when I clicked on one of careers positons